# Why do I get null?

Tags: kotlin, null-pointer

My console says

```
Math: 5.0
false

English: 3.0
true

Physics: null
false

Chemistry: null
false
```

This sound ok, but in my Code I had a Exception-Code. I do not understand why I get `null` here:

```
Physics: null
Chemistry: null
```

```
class Course(
    val name: String
){
    var grade: Double? = null
        set(value){
            try {
                if (value != null && value >= 1.0 && value <= 6.0){
                    field = value
                }

            } catch ( e: NullPointerException ){
                field = 6.0
            }
        }

    var passed: Boolean? = null
        get(){
            return (this.grade ?:6.0) <= 4.0
        }

}

fun main(){
    val math = Course (" MATH ")
    math.grade = 5.0 //valid

    val english = Course (" ENGLISH ")
    english.grade = 3.0 // valid

    val physics = Course (" PHYSICS ")
    physics.grade = 0.7 // invalide

    val chemistry = Course (" CHEMISTRY ")
    chemistry.grade = 6.3 // invalide

    println("Math: " + math.grade )
    println( math.passed )
    println()

    println("English: " + english.grade )
    println( english.passed )
    println()

    println("Physics: " + physics.grade )
    println( physics.passed )
    println()

    println("Chemistry: " + chemistry.grade )
    println( chemistry.passed )
    println()

}
```

I want to get here

```
try {
    if (value != null && value >= 1.0 && value <= 6.0) {
        field = value
    }
} catch (e: NullPointerException ) {
    field = 6.0
}
```

for field 6.0, but not "null" how can I fix this Problem?

Comment: Nothing in your `try` block will actually throw an exception. Please consult your book / guide / course / Google on how Java exceptions work.

Comment: Add an `else { value = 6.0}` because nothing can throw there is nothing to catch

Answer (score 2):

Here's your variable and its setter function:

```
var grade: Double? = null
    set(value) {
        if (value != null && value >= 1.0 && value <= 6.0) {
            field = value
        }
    }
```

I removed the *try/catch* because it doesn't actually do anything - we'll get to that in a minute! So what you're left with is a setter that **only updates if `value` is between *1.0* and *6.0***. If it's outside that range, or *null*, the `if` condition fails and `field` (the actual stored value for the variable) isn't changed. And because its initial value is `null`, that's why you're still getting *null* when you print its value.

---

You should probably read up on exceptions and what the `try/catch` blocks actually do - [here's the Java tutorial about it](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html) (the [Kotlin docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/exceptions.html) assume you know this, and really just talk about how Kotlin approaches it).

But basically - if you try to call a function with a parameter that isn't supposed to be *null*, or you try to call a method or access a property on an object that's actually *null*, that will create an error called an `Exception` - something has gone wrong, and your code can't handle it. This exception will bubble back up through the call chain, and eventually crash your program, unless something in that chain `catch`es it and handles it.

So by wrapping code in a `try` block, you're recognising that there's a *possibility of an exception happening*, and in the `catch` block you handle them (or certain types of exception, like a `NullPointerException`). And that's where you have your fallback behaviour, setting `field` to *6.0*.

The problem is the code in your `try` block **won't throw an NPE** - there's nothing happening in there that's dangerous, you're even explicitly handling the possibility of null! (Which Kotlin forces you to do anyway, to avoid NPEs - it's designed around null-safety.)

---

The other issue is this - what exactly are you trying to do with the `catch` block? It's a fallback value, right? But you're only attempting to handle nulls anyway - what about the other cases, where `value` isn't null, but it's outside the valid range? Even if the try/catch trick *did* work, it wouldn't handle the case you're testing, which is setting an out-of-range value.

So really, you should be doing something like a simple `if/else`:

```
    set(value) {
        if (value != null && value >= 1.0 && value <= 6.0) {
            field = value
        } else {
            field = 6.0
        }
    }
```

There you go! Your `if` condition already defines the valid values, so you just need to add an `else` block that covers everything else. There are some other ways to express this too, but this is the simplest, and most important to understand.